# Oracle SQL view not working with case when

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am creating below view in Oracle database

```
CREATE  VIEW "view"."table2" ( "type1", "type2") AS 
  SELECT

        CASE WHEN n.flag2 = 'Y' AND n.flag1 = 'Y' THEN 'n1' 
        WHEN n.flag2 = 'N' AND n.flag1 = 'Y' THEN 'n2' WHEN n.flag2 = 'Y' AND n.flag1 = 'N' THEN 'n3' else 'n4' end as type1,
        CASE WHEN post_code in ('AB') THEN 'w' WHEN post_code in ('NB') THEN 'e' ELSE 'o' END AS type2

    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                
                CASE WHEN date1 > SYSDATE + 1 AND email11 IS NOT NULL  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS flag1,
                CASE WHEN date2 > SYSDATE + 12 AND email2 IS NOT NULL  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS flag2,
                post_code
                
            FROM
                table1 m
            WHERE
               date3 > sysdate ) n;
```

When I run below is working

select * from table2;

but when i run select type1 from table2;  it through me error

invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

I have tried multiple ways to modify the view but none of my approach works

Comment: Post the `DDL` of the `table1` without it there is no chance to help. Obvious is also if you define in a view a column as `"type1"` (=quoted) you *must* use it quoted in the query as well -> `select "type1" from table2`

Comment: Note also that dubbing the schema as `view` and the view `table` you are simple asking for troubles...

Comment: please add sample data as text together with a select statement  from the view which throws the error.

Comment: If you have defined the DDL as `CREATE  VIEW "view"."table2"` then `SELECT * FROM table2` will not work as Oracle converts unquoted identifiers to upper-case and `"table2"` is not the same as `"TABLE2"` so you either have two tables named `"table2" and `"TABLE2"` or your `SELECT` query should not work because the table name is the wrong case.

Comment: Following on from that, if you have defined the columns of the view as `( "type1", "type2")` then `select type1 from table2;` will not work because, again, Oracle converts unquoted identifier to upper case and `"type1"` is not the same as `"TYPE1"`. You can try, as @MarmiteBomber said, `SELECT "type1" from table2` but you probably want `SELECT "type1" FROM "table2"` or `SELECT "type1" FROM "view"."table2";`.

Comment: However, what you really should be doing is **NOT USING QUOTED IDENTIFIERS**.

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vLkztrdJ) showing the problem with unquoted vs. quoted identifiers.

Comment: Notice that `create view "view1"."table2"` refers to user `"view1"` and will fail unless user "view1" exists.